# Transcription and pronunciation of the 'un-' prefix in General American English

Tags: pronunciation, prefixes, ipa, negative-prefixes

What's the correct transcription and pronunciation of the 'un-' prefix in General American English? 
Cambridge Online dictionary provides [the following transcription](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/un): /ʌn/

It's the same [in words with this prefix](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/undo): /ʌnˈdu/.
Why do they use the /ʌ/ and not the /ə/ (schwa)? It's the /ə/ sound that typically occurs in unstressed syllables.
Thank you.

Comment: Your example *undue* has stress on both syllables, it seems to me.  (Perhaps a secondary stress in the first syllable, but not unstressed.) Indeed, that often occurs... *unwashed*, *unknown*, *unclean*.  This may explain Cambridge Online Dictionary.

Comment: The prefix *un-* usually has secondary stress, so it's not reduced to a schwa: *unable* is not an exact homophone of *enable*. (Although since the majority of Americans pronounce schwa and /ʌ/ with the same vowel, the distinction will often be quite subtle.  Many, if not all, of the rest of us, me included, use /ʌ/ and not /ə/ in *un-*.)

Comment: Phonemically, there's no difference between /ə/ and /ʌ/. They both name the same phoneme, at least in American English. [ʌ] -- the **phone**, not the phoneme -- is the allophone that occurs with primary stress, while [ə], shading off to [ɨ] or syllabic resonants, occurs most often as the allophone without primary stress. On the basic principle that the most common allophone should be the name of the phoneme, I use /ə/ instead of /ʌ/. Also, people vary considerably in their individual pronunciation of reduced vowels; individual variation usually swamps "official" pronunciations.

Comment: @JohnLawler: so do you pronounce *unable* and *enable* in exactly the same way? For me, that's a minimal pair between /ʌ/ and /ə/.

Comment: Depends on what preceded it. If it was _be_ or _to_ (among the most common choices), they'd both decay to a syllabic nasal following the /y/ or /w/, and be indistinguishable outside of context.

Comment: The vowel in _unable_ is slightly further back than _enable_, at least in my teacher voice. Otherwise pen-pin merger fronts _enable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Phonemically, there's no difference between /ə/ and /ʌ/. They both name the same phoneme, at least in American English. [ʌ] -- the **phone**, not the phoneme -- is the allophone that occurs with primary stress, while [ə], shading off to [ɨ] or syllabic resonants, occurs most often as the allophone without primary stress. On the basic principle that the most common allophone should be the name of the phoneme, I use /ə/ instead of /ʌ/. Also, people vary considerably in their individual pronunciation of reduced vowels; individual variation usually swamps "official" pronunciations.

Answer (score 1):

Different Americans speak differently. Some have secondary stress on the first syllable of *undo*, and most other words with the prefix *un-*, in which case /ʌnˈdu/ is a better transcriptions. See [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/undo). From the comments, some apparently don't. In this case, /ənˈdu/ would be a better transcriptions.

The difference between no stress and secondary stress, and the consequent variation in the quality of the vowel (for those Americans who pronounce /ʌ/ with a different vowel from /ə/) are relatively minor sound changes.